# How to get the orientation of my device when I have a fixed orientation in my Activity?

Tags: android, orientation

My Activity has a fixed orientation in Portrait and I want it to stay in portrait.
`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

It would not make sense for the activity to do it responsive.

My Problem: I have a fragment in the application which contains a textView.
I want the fragment to be responsive so that the user can read the text.

I tried to get the orientation from the onConfigurationChanged Methode but this isn´t called when I turn my device since it always stays portrait.

Now I wanted to figure out the orientation of my device and then animate the fragment to turn it. But I have not found a way to get the orientation of my device but only the one of my Activity.

I also tried to set the fragment orientation with the methode above different than the orientation of the activity but that didn´t work (the orientation was always the same as the one of the activity.) .

Now I really don´t know what to do anymore. 
Does anybody know how I can get the orientation of the device independent from the orientation on the Activity? -> or has an other idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: You want to detect the  orientation of the device right?

Comment: @Chandrakanth yes of the device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `OrientationEventListener` to get the orientation angle value.

```
OrientationEventListener listener=new OrientationEventListener(this,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {

            @Override
            public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
                Log.d(tag, "Orientation = "+orientation);
            }
        };

        listener.enable();
```

Based on orientation value you can determine the orientation of the device.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the android sensors directly to determine orientation: [Sensors Overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html)

Hope this helps

(But I can't really understand why you would want to do this without rotating the activity..)

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense.Yah, I think the easiest way (possibly the only way) will be to use the sensors.